# Multiple text insertion in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, command, text-editor

Can someone help me how to write a piece of command that will insert some text in multiple places (given column and row) of a given file that already contains data. For example: old_data is a file that contains:

```
A
```

And I wish to get new_data that will contain:

```
A 1
```

I read something about awk and sed commands, but I don't believe to understand how to incorporate these, to get what I want.

I would like to add up, that this command I would like to use as a part of script

```
for b in ./*/ ; do (cd "$b" && command); done
```

If we imagine content of old_data as a matrix of elements *{An*m}* where n corresponds to number of row and m to number of column of this matrix, I wish to manipulate with matrix so that I could add new elements. **A** in old-data has coordinates **(1,1)**. In new_data therefore, I wish to assign 1 to a matrix element that has coordinates **(1,3)**.
If we compare content of old_data and new_data we see that (1,2) element corresponds to space (it is empty).

Comment: Is there a logic behind that output?

Comment: @JamesBrown I believe I didn't understand your question. I used A B C D to label old data and numbers to label new data (which is either text or number).

Comment: @user406046 and why the `1` coming after the `A` line, but the other numbers in the same line as the given letter? Also from where we get the numbers? We understand that you're new here, (welcome), but please, read the [ask] and [mcve]. (and also the [help] and [tour]) :)

Comment: ... and now (after you added your code-fragment) is even **less** clear. You want visit all directories in your current one, and want do some `command`. And what the `command` should do? The above insertions? In which files?

Comment: Please also describe what's in **(1,2)**.

Comment: @agc nothing it is not zero it doesn't exists it should correspond to space :)

Comment: @jm666 i tried to simplify as much as I could. Exactly, the goal is to visit of the directories , to change the content of file old_data and create new data by using mysterious command.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear to me what you are asking for, but I suspect you are saying that you would like a way to insert some given text in to a particular row and column.  Perhaps:

```
$ cat input
A
B
C
D
$ row=2 column=2 text="This is some new data"
$ awk 'NR==row {$column = new_data " " $column}1' row=$row column=$column new_data="$text" input
A
B  This is some new data 
C
D
```

Comment: I believe you understood correctly. But old_data is some file. The piece of command I have written in the above question is in the form of script. So this script should operate as follows: script old_data > new_data

Comment: So redirect the output of awk: `awk ... input > new_data` (I've used the file named `input` instead of `old_data`)

Answer (score 0):

This `bash` & unix tools code works:

```
# make the input files.
echo {A..D} | tr ' ' '\n' > abc ; echo {1..4} | tr ' ' '\n' > 123
# print as per previous OP spec
head -1q abc 123 ; paste abc 123 123 | tail -n +2
```

Output:

```
A
1
B   2   2
C   3   3
D   4   4
```

---

Version #3, (using commas as more visible separators), as per newest OP spec:

```
# for the `sed` code change the `2` to whatever column needs deleting. 
paste -d, abc 123 123 | sed 's/[^,]*//2'
```

Output:

```
A,,1
B,,2
C,,3
D,,4
```

The same, with *tab* delimiters (less visually obvious):

```
paste abc 123 123 | sed 's/[^\t]*//2'
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement this. Sorry for the change of post.